# Recommended nodes per TB of data in bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigdata

I am looking to build a single (history) table in Bigtable that will be 30TB and growing. I expect a single daily batch load of 200GB, and occasional batch queries within a key range. What guidance is available for the number of TB per node in Bigtable? I have read some oblique posts for Cassandra that suggests 1TB usable per node, and some other posts that suggest 6-12TB per HBase node. I cannot find any clear guidance in Google Bigtable docs.

Comment: Offtopic. this is more DBA stuff - try the DBA site.

Comment: Not really dependent on size -- it's more important about the volume of traffic.  Most users will scale their instance at # of nodes needed for non-batch, then increase the number of nodes temporarily for the batch job.

Comment: Les, that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Engineering has said:  It really depends on the workload - you should try a prolonged multi-day experiment, ideally you will will have a large node count and import all the data, then resize to the smallest node size and then perform the read/write workload that you expect for a few days, specifically monitor the cpu usage as well.

We are working on a note about stale / cold uses cases.